# サーバー (origin) から消したはずのブランチが git branch -a すると出現する

Tags: git

表題のとおりとなります。

サーバー（origin）から消したはずのブランチが（例えばhoge)が

Amazon Linuxのgitで下記操作をすると

`$ git branch -a | grep hoge`

> remotes/origin/hoge

と出てしまいます。

Macで同様に、

`$ git branch -a | grep hoge`
した場合は何も表示されません。

ソースツリーでもhogeブランチはoriginから消えていることは確認済みです。

gitのバージョンの違いで挙動が違うとかでしょうか？
Amazon: git version 2.1.0
Mac: git version 2.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示されているのは、ローカルに存在しているリモート追跡ブランチです。 `git fetch -p` を実行すると、 fetch の際に、リモート上から存在しなくなったブランチの、リモート追跡ブランチを削除できます。

Comment: 消せました。　Macだと `-p` をつけずにいけたという疑問がのこりますが、ソースツリーが裏で勝手にやってたのかな...